# How to pass data using PopAsync?

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, xamarin.forms.entry

I have the following situation:
I have an app, where I want to create notes using a special page for it. I have VM with ObservableCollection NoteItems with all the notes. When I want to create a new note, I add a new note to this ObservableCollection and pass this new note using BindingContext

```c#
    var editingPage = new EditingPage();
    editingPage.BindingContext = NoteItems[NoteItems.Count - 1].Text; 
    Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(editingPage);
```

In the editing page I have an Entry field

```xml
       <Entry
         x:Name="EdtingPageEntryField"
         Text="{Binding Text}"
         Placeholder="Enter a note"
       />
```

, which is Binding his text with the Text parameter of a NoteItem.
The problem is that if I change the text in entry field, it does not automatically apply to a Text parameter of a NoteItem. That is why I want to pass this text when I close this EditingPage(go back to the MainPage). So the question is, how can I pass this Text parameter to a NoteItem element from NoteItems ObservableCollection, which is located in VM.

UPD. The value of NoteItem, which is located in NoteItems does not change

UPD2. I was wrong about the value of NoteItem, it has been changed, but the new value does not display on MainPage, that is why I used INotifyPropertyChanged, but it did not work.

Here is Note Item class

```c#
public class NoteItem
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string text;
        public string Text 
        { 
            get { return text; } 
            set 
            { 
                if(text != value) 
                { 
                    text = value; 
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            } 
        }
```

And MainPage.xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:NoteItemViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <FlexLayout>
        
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding NoteItems}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        
    </FlexLayout>
'''
```

Comment: instead of passing just the Text property, try passing the entire `NoteItem` object

Comment: This does not help, I still can not change the Text parameter inside EditingPage

Comment: are you actually checking the value in the debugger to see if it changed?  Or are you just looking at the UI to see the change?

Comment: I just look at the UI

Comment: are you using INotifyPropertyChanged?  The UI will not dynamically update if you are not.

Comment: no, I don't, how can I do that?

Comment: google it.  There are a billion existing articles on it, there is no need to write another one

Comment: now I checked the value and saw that the value is not editing

Comment: Please update your post with the relevant code for your model.  And take the time to properly format it, please.

Comment: I have updated all the things, you can check it now. Sorry for formatting, that is my first question on stackoverflow, and sorry for all this spam and other things - I am just starting developing something, that is why that all is quite hard for me to understand and do the thing correctly:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to dynamically update the UI, your model must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public class NoteItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  ...
}
```

simply adding a `PropertyChanged` method is not the same as implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  You must add the interface to the class definition so that the binding mechanism knows that your class has implemented it

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved my problem:)